# Data Augmentation Layer in Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to add data augmentation as a layer to a model but I'm having what I assume is a shape issue. I tried specifying the input shape in the augmented layer as well. When I take out the `data_augmentation` layer from the model it runs fine.

```
preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

````py
  data_augmentation_layer = keras.Sequential([                                    
  preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
  preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomWidth(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomHeight(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomContrast(0.2)                                  
], name='data_augmentation')



  model = keras.Sequential([
  data_augmentation_layer,
  Conv2D(filters=32,
         kernel_size=1,
         strides=1,
         input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
  Activation(activation='relu'),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Conv2D(filters=32,
         kernel_size=1,
         strides=1),
  Activation(activation='relu'),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])```

 The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layers `RandomWidth` and `RandomHeight` are causing this error, since they are leading to `None` dimensions: See the comment [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14864#issuecomment-906735774):

> [...]RandomHeight will lead to a None shape on
> the height dimension, as not all outputs from the layer will be the
> same height (by design). That is ok for things like the Conv2D layer,
> which can accept variable shaped image input (with None shapes on some
> dimensions).
>
> This will not work for then calling into a Flatten followed by a
> Dense, because the flattened batches will also be of variable size
> (because of the variable height), and the Dense layer needs a fixed
> shape for the last dimension. You could probably pad output of flatten
> before the dense, but if you want this architecture, you may just want
> to avoid image augmentation layer that lead to a variable output
> shape.

So instead of using a `Flatten` layer, you could, for example, use a `GlobalMaxPool2D` layer, which does not need to know the other dimensions beforehand:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data_augmentation_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([                                    
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip('horizontal',
         input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomWidth(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomHeight(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.2)                                  
], name='data_augmentation')

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
data_augmentation_layer,
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
        kernel_size=1,
        strides=1),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
        kernel_size=1,
        strides=1),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

print(model.summary())
```

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 data_augmentation (Sequenti  (None, None, None, 3)    0         
 al)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)    128       
                                                                 
 activation_8 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)    0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling  (None, None, None, 32)   0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)    1056      
                                                                 
 activation_9 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)    0         
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling2d_1 (Glo  (None, 32)               0         
 balMaxPooling2D)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,217
Trainable params: 1,217
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Yes thanks that did the trick. @AloneTogether

Comment: I was looking for this only from very long time finally got it, Thanks 