# Keras data augmentation layers - erroring

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) from Tensorflow to build my first image classifier. To improve my model accuracy and reduce loss I wish to employ data augmentation, and I cannot seem to call `layers.RandomFlip` or `layers.RandomRotation` without throwing this error within Anaconda3 and Jupyter, with Tensorflow 2.10:

`` ValueError: Argument `alg` got unsupported value 3. Supported values are 1 for the Philox algorithm and 2 for the ThreeFry algorithm. ``

To start, my shape is defined through a feature extraction layer built using the following:

```
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    inception_v3,
    input_shape=(299, 299, 3),
    trainable=False)
```

I have tried calling the augmentation functions within their own sequential layers variable:

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.15),
])
```

And also tried instantiating within the model itself, with the same result:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_extractor_layer,
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.15),
  layers.Dropout(0.15),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
```

When it doesn't error out immediately (using the former example), I tried passing the layer through to a plot to show the random rotation and flipping. I did this using this code block:

```
for image, _ in train_ds.take(1):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
  first_image = image[0]
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    augmented_image = data_augmentation(tf.expand_dims(first_image, 0))
    plt.imshow(augmented_image[0] / 255)
    plt.axis('off')
```

I am presented with the following debug output:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

Argument `alg` got unsupported value 3. Supported values are 1 for the Philox algorithm and 2 for the ThreeFry algorithm.

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None
```

To me, this seems to imply that the order of my matrix shape is influencing the error. I thought that the last value in the shape, the 3, is being misinterpreted as the RNG formula rather than the 3 color bands in my dataset. Going back to the plot above, I swapped the order of the expanded dimension, putting this new value at the end of the shape rather than the start, with `augmented_image = data_augmentation(tf.expand_dims(first_image, -1))`  but it did not solve the issue.

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'random_rotation' (type RandomRotation).

...

 ValueError: Argument `alg` got unsupported value 3. Supported values are 1 for the Philox algorithm and 2 for the ThreeFry algorithm.


Call arguments received by layer 'random_rotation' (type RandomRotation):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(299, 299, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
```

As I was writing this post I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455053/data-augmentation-layer-in-keras-sequential-model) but I still get the same output error attempting to format my layer structure in the recommended format.

Is my shape incorrect?  Is there a better way to augment my image dataset in Tensorflow 2.10?

Full traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [8], line 3
      1 num_classes = len(class_names)
----> 3 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      4   feature_extractor_layer,
      5   layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
      6   layers.RandomRotation(0.15),
      7   layers.Dropout(0.15),
      8   tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))#,activation='softmax'
      9 ])
     11 predictions = model(image_batch)
     13 predictions.shape

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py:205, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    203 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    204 try:
--> 205   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    206 finally:
    207   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\stateful_random_ops.py:147, in _get_state_size(alg)
    145   return THREEFRY_STATE_SIZE
    146 else:
--> 147   raise ValueError(
    148       f"Argument `alg` got unsupported value {alg}. Supported values are "
    149       f"{RNG_ALG_PHILOX} for the Philox algorithm and {RNG_ALG_THREEFRY} for "
    150       f"the ThreeFry algorithm.")

ValueError: Argument `alg` got unsupported value 3. Supported values are 1 for the Philox algorithm and 2 for the ThreeFry algorithm.
```

Comment: Always upload the full traceback, not the **just** the last error.

Comment: Updated with full traceback at bottom of post

Comment: What is the value of `inception_v3`? Shouldn't you do data augmentation *before* feature extraction?

Comment: @elbe `inception_v3` is a hyperlink to the feature vector on tfhub: https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/4

The same error in my post arises trying to augment my dataset before building the extractor layer, after breaking my dataset up into `train_ds` and `val_ds`, normalizing, and autotuning my cache.